# Issues in Adapter to Fragment in intent using web services

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-recyclerview

When i click on a button in recycler view adapter then one popup is appeared from service then it will  go to next fragment.i write code like this it shows error how to solve this?

```
  dialog_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new ConfirmAsyncTask().execute();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,OngoingFragment.class);
                  v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.digitaltoday.mpsb2b, PID: 25101
                                                                                 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.digitaltoday.mpsb2b/adaptersandfragments.OngoingFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                     at

Comment: You need to declare activity OngoingFragment in your Manifest

Comment: Do you have any inner class activity?

Comment: i dont have any inner class only variables in OnBindviewholder method in that variable i have one button  variable when i click it show error it dont go to fragment

Comment: guys try to understand i am not using fragment in xml i am extending with fragment class

Comment: You can't start Fragment using StartActivity use FragmentManager instead.

Comment: @A.asha As I understand, you were trying to start a fragment with `startActivity` so far. Were you able to solve your problem using the suggestions that the others posted, or would you like me to post a detailed answer (with code) for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Activity beside Fragment then add your activity in Manifest file. and if your are using Fragment then use FragmentManager to switch your fragment instead of Intent.

Comment: i am not using activity i am using in intent in Recycler view adapter like this   holder.accept_linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() in that my "question " is putting then i am getting error

Comment: @A.asha i get your point, but you are trying to open an Activity which is not declared in Manifest file.

Comment: @A.asha  add this line in your manifest file..<activity android:name=".OngoingFragment"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can not start a `Fragment` like starting an `Activity`.
[See this.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)